# What is the notation for `or` in security rules?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have searched for this very thoroughly but sadly couldn't find any helpful answer or by that matter any answer at all. Basically, this is how you block somebody who is a stranger, is not authenticated or is another user for accessing somebody's document in Cloud Firestore:

```
match /collection/{userId} {
    allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
}
```

But after that we also have more complicated rules like:

```
allow write: if (above snippet) && request.resource.data.write_variable == 1;
```

That's great because even though Firestore is a noSQL, shema-less database, we can kind of set some standards for the `write` operation, or even `read` operation. In my case, what I want however is allow the user to write to a document if these conditions apply:

- Is authenticated and the `userId` is the same as its `uid`. Meaning he can access only his document.
- Allow `write` if the `write_variable`, which is a field within my document, is equal to 1 **OR** equal to 5.

And that is the problem I can't seem to find the operator for `or`. Is it: `||`, `|` or something else. I can't really test, because I can't mess with my already working app, so please answer with a straight answer(is possible, or not, and if yes how?). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logical OR operator in Firebase security rules is exactly what you'd expect: `||`.  All operators dealing with boolean values are documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Boolean).

Comment: Thanks very much. Was like searching for over an hour and couldn't find a link. Unthinkable that I am speaking with someone from Google ;)

Comment: Just a question: So, for instance, I can do this: `if request.resource.data.variable == 1 || request.resource.data.variable == 5 && request.auth != null`?

Comment: Sure, and you should probably create a new project to test your rules in isolation from your production project.

Comment: I have created one. I actually created a new project and tested my code. But then after I transferred the security rules back to my main project, then I remembered my `or` problem. Great now I can continue with development. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is a very useful tool called `Simulator` in the firebase console - you can test the rules before saving it - no need to worry about existing code. As for the `or` operator, it's this:

```
`||`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but @Doug answered it way before, so I will have to tick his answer. Yes, I'm aware of the simulator. That's how I do most of my tests.

Comment: Yup, was waiting for 10 minutes to pass to accept the answer and almost forgot it. Thanks for the reminder.

Comment: Please upvote this question for more people to see this :)